# Drawing sprite on top of a Tile Map

Tags: c++, opengl

So I have a 2D array which acts as a map for my tiles to be drawn.

```
int sMap[12][20] = {
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
  {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1},
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
  {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
};
```

Once my tiles have been loaded in, I use this `function()` to place the tiles:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++){
    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++){
        if    (sMap[y][x] == 1)
            glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, brick1);
        else if (sMap[y][x] == 2)
            glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, brick2);
        else
            glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, wall );

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(float(x + offsetx),     float(MAP_SIZEY - (y + offsety)), 0.0f); 
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(float(x + 1 + offsetx), float(MAP_SIZEY - (y + offsety)), 0.0f); 
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(float(x + 1 + offsetx), float(MAP_SIZEY - (y + 1 + offsety)), 0.0f); 
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(float(x + offsetx),     float(MAP_SIZEY - (y + 1 + offsety)), 0.0f);
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

I think I may have confused myself with the coordinate system of the tiles because when I draw a basic `OpenGL` square which acts as a sprite, I just get a black screen upon running the program.

I'm unsure whether this means the scale of the sprite to the tiles is wrong, or whether the sprite and tiles are on different `Z`planes...

I would appreciate if someone could explain the coordinate system in case I don't understand it as much as I thought and also advise me how to draw an `OpenGL`square on the same coordinates.

Currently I have this to draw my basic sprite:

```
struct RECT{float x, y, w, h;};
RECT sprite = {0, 0, 10, 10};

void drawSprite (RECT rect){
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    
        glVertex3f(rect.x, rect.y, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(rect.x, rect.y+rect.h, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(rect.x+rect.w, rect.y+rect.h, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(rect.x+rect.w, rect.y, 0.0);
    glEnd();
}
```

**EDIT:**

resize screen:

```
glViewport(0,0,width,height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,0.1f,20.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

draw scene:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(10.0f, 8.0f, 20.0f, 10.0f, 8.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glTranslatef(5.0f,4.0f,0.0f);
draw_tiles();
draw_sprite();
```

Comment: "the coordinate system"...what coordinate system?  You haven't shown either your `GL_PROJECTION` *or* `GL_MODELVIEW` matrices.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I'll edit my question right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the draw_tiles function it looks like you might be passing incorrect coordinates - maybe you should be multiplying the x and y values by your tile size.

Also try turning off depth testing and backface culling to help resolve your black screen problem.

```
glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
glDisable( GL_CULL_FACE );
```